# Object detection in RGB-D images

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision

Can you please recommend papers/github or smth about object detection on RGB-D images (NOT 3d cloud points).The result should still be objects in rectangles in the 2d image, as in the usual methods for object detection like YOLO and others. All I can find is Silent Object detection methods, but it seems like not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good primer to start your research.
https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.09236

There are many open-source implementations. Try some and ask on stackoverflow when you get stuck.